# How much history does CPU Usage History in XP's task manager show?

Tags: windows-xp, history, cpu-usage, task-manager

Could anyone tell me how much history, in time (e.g. seconds or minutes), the CPU Usage History panel in the Task Manager show (see the image below)? I'm particularly interested on the XP, but also wonder if it changes across different flavours of Windows.

[image]

Comment: You can also change this via the View | Update Speed menu in taskman

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that each square still represents 6 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows XP, Vista, win7 each Sqaure represents 6 seconds

Comment: May I ask where you got this from, i.e. did you test it or read it somewhere?

Comment: I tested it for myself

Answer (score 2):

On my Vista system, each square represents 6 seconds.